# iOS: enable/disable sound of push notification programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, push-notification

I want to add a functionality in my app and that is, user can enable and disable push notification sound. Here is the UI:

[image]

I am using the following code for enabling and disabling sound:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes;
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
        //
        if(sound==0 || sound==1)
        {
        allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        }
        else if(sound==2)
        {
            allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        [FIRApp configure];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                     name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
```

I am using firebase for push notifications.

Comment: Could you please update notification payload? Better try a notification payload without `sound` key instead of re-registering each time user on/off notification setting.

Comment: but if one user enabled the notification sound and 2nd user disabled the sound. how can I play sound for the user who is enabled the notification sound?

Comment: This setting should be saved in server db per user. And while triggering push for specific user, check for the setting and send payload accordingly

Comment: Is Firebase allow this?

Comment: @MuhammadUmair have u done this?? I mean stop notification sound from application via coding?

Comment: @Monika Patel Nup..

Comment: @MonikaPatel, have you tried it?, does it work?